# datatable ajax clear() draw(); with new parameters

Tags: javascript, datatables

I was looking for a way reload this **DataTable** with new params in the request (user).
The code works: the draw function is reloading but the user value (usrs( is not passed to ajax
Please see the code below:

```
var usrs;

      table = $('table#logs').DataTable({
                        
        "columns": [
            
            {"data": "date"},                                                   
            {"data": "where"},  
            {"data": "action"}, 
            {"data": "user_name"},
                                                        
        ],
        "processing": true,
        
                    
        "serverSide": true,
         
        "ajax": {
            url: 'logs',
            type: 'POST',
    timeout: 60000,
    "data": {
            
        "user" : usrs,

            }
            
        }
    });

    

$('#logusers').change(function(){
    
    usrs = $('#logusers option:selected').val();
    table.clear().draw();
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting data at on change event
get it at data property of ajax as shown below
and at the server end check if it exist/not.

```
$(function(){

      var usrs;     
      table = $('table#logs').DataTable({
                        
        "columns": [
            
            {"data": "date"},                                                   
            {"data": "where"},  
            {"data": "action"}, 
            {"data": "user_name"},
                                                        
        ],
        "processing": true,
        
                    
        "serverSide": true,
         
        "ajax": {
            url: 'logs',
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 60000,
            "data": function ( data ) 
             { //updated 
                data.user = $('#logusers option:selected').val();
                
             }
            }
         });

        $('#logusers').change(function()
        { //updated 
          table.ajax.reload();
        });


})
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but $('#logusers option:selected').val() is not passed to DataTable I should put into a variable but also does not work.

Comment: "user" : $('#logusers option:selected').val() does not work.. btw if i make an alert in the change function it works, so it's just something preventing ajax to get the value.

Comment: have tried wrapping your script in document ready function? if yes what do you see in network tab when url: 'logs' request fired.

Comment: what do you see in network tab when url: 'logs' request fired?

Comment: it' empty. I see: user: ""

Comment: updated answer to fetch data and reload it on change event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216621/discussion-between-robert-and-sandeep-modak).

Comment: I have no idea about how to refetch data. I thought the reload function already does it. I  even tried to put it all in a function as well with no success.

Comment: try to log in console as i have suggested in discussion chat